# How to code group application commands on discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, bots

I've been searching for how to group application (interaction) commands for awhile and I haven't found any solution.

I want that when I use "/say" on Discord bot, it shows two options "/say message" and "/say embed", but I haven't found any solutions yet.

Does anyone know what I should do?

I can't seem to understand the discord.py documentation.

Comment: This is only one example and there are multiple way of grouping app_commands, if you are using a cog, you can group your app_commands [like this](https://github.com/PaulMarisOUMary/Discord-Bot/blob/main/cogs/me.py).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a simple way, at least for me, is to make the class name the word you want then add the slash commands.

example:

```py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from discord import app_commands

class say(commands.GroupCog):
    def __init__(self, client: commands.Bot):
        self.client = client (client or bot depending on which you use)



    @app_commands.command(name="message")
    async def message()
      .....

    @app_commands.command(name="embed")
    async def embed()
      ....
```

in the example i use `@app_commands` since i pulled the example from a different file from my main python file.

basically any command you have under a groupcog will automatically take the name of the cog followed by the command name.